# how to fix the Failed to index Provenance Events error?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a problem on nifi at each step of my flow I have this error:

> 11:44:07 **CESTERROR
> Failed to index Provenance Events. See logs for more information.**
> i find in nifi-app.log
> [image]
> however there is no error and my nifi flow is working well
> I have no error on the processor but the error is displayed at the top right

the nifi.properties looks good,
[image]

Comment: Did you look in nifi-app.log?

Comment: i add the picture of the  log

Comment: it is a processor that I exported as a template from a server and I imported it into this server

Comment: What is `nifi.provenance.repository.implementation` set to? How many FlowFiles are in queues? Can you upgrade from 1.9.2 which is more than 2 years old?

Comment: how do I know if nifi.provenance.repository.implementation is set?
there is only one flowfiles in the queue and that puts an error on each processor

Comment: Check your `nifi.properties` file to find the setting. There is only 1 FlowFile across all queues in the entire NiFi cluster?

Comment: i just checked, the nifi.properties looks good, I added the photo of the properties
there is only one file across all queues nifi